# Init function on resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having some problems with this function running inside `$(window).resize()`

How do I get the `IndexGrid.init()` function to run again inside `$(window).resize()`?

```
var IndexGrid = {

    init: function() {
        this.initGrid();
        this.infoSize();
    },

    initGrid: function() {
      // Function
    },

    infoSize: function() {
     // Function
    }   
}   

IndexGrid.init();
```

Comment: $(window).resize(IndexGrid.init);

Comment: $(window).resize(function (){ IndexGrid.init(); /* anything else */ });

Comment: @jasonscript thanks this works! I tried using $(window).resize(IndexGrid.init); but it wasn't working.